# How to assign multiple roles for a single user using Wavemaker?

Tags: user-controls, access-control, rad, wavemaker

We have been building applications using Wavemaker's application building platform and now we wanted to assign multiple roles to a single user? Can this be done and how?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement, create a separate table for user roles, say *user_roles*.

For Example, USER table contains the fields: user ID , Name etc
USER_ROLES table contains:  user ID, Role_Name etc.

Using the fields as mentioned above gives provision to have multiple roles for a single user.